# How to view images on GUI without a static path

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, xpce

I was wondering if it is possible to send an image in my GUI but have the path saved as a fact in my database. Instead of calling it using
`resource(logo,image,image('logo.jpg')).` Is it posible to call a variable inside `('logo.jpg')` that will change depending on the fact that is called?.

Answer (score 1):

The better hint I can give you is to learn to use XPCE live documentation.
From swipl-win open menu

`\ Help \ XPCE (GUI) manual...`

From there (the small window titled `XPCE Manual`) open menu `\ File \ Demo Programs`
and from the list proposed click `Image viewer`. Click button `[ Source ]` and at bottom of file there is the code example you're looking for.

A bit of DRY could turn it in a reusable component.
For instance:

```
/*  File:    pce_image_view.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: May 19 2019
    Purpose: answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/56201622/874024
*/

:- module(pce_image_view, [pce_image_view/1]).
:- use_module(library(pce)).

pce_image_view(Filename) :-
    new(I, image(Filename)),
    !,
    new(B, bitmap(I)),
    new(P, picture),
    send(P, display, B),
    send(P, open).
```

save the file, consult it and call:

```
?- pce_image_view('/home/carlo/Pictures/prova1.jpg').
true.
```

Sorry then demo program - it's a fairly complete local file typed browser - seems not working right now out-of-the-box. Anyway, some higher level constructs made available by recent language development could be applied to make the API more comfortable.